# RSpec - testing race conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, race-condition

I'm trying to write a RSpec controller test checking for race conditions based on [this blog post](http://blog.arkency.com/2015/09/testing-race-conditions/), but created `Thread`s don't "see" the `User`s created at the beginning of the test.
The blog post suggests to change `config.use_transactional_fixtures` to `false`, but even with this setting `User`s aren't visible.

Here's the test:

```
it "avoids race conditions" do
  u = create(:user, :without_settings)
  u_2 = create(:user, :without_settings)

  wait_for_it = true

  threads = Array.new(4).map {
    Thread.new do
      true while wait_for_it
      # send the request
      signed_post(
        u,
        api_v1_blockades_path,
        params: {
          blockade: {
            blocked_user_id: u_2.id,
            reason: 11
          }
        }
      )
    end
  }

  wait_for_it = false
  threads.map(&:join)

  expect(u.blockades.count).to eq(1)
end
```

For authentication i'm using the [ApiAuth gem](https://github.com/mgomes/api_auth):

```
before_action :api_authenticate

private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: ApiAuth.access_id(request))
end

def api_authenticate
  head(:unauthorized) unless current_user && ApiAuth.authentic?(request, current_user.auth_token)
end
```

Comment: What is the actual error? A thread should be able to see the parent thread's var's until the child thread changes them (copy on write).

Comment: @Kris When i run the test on one thread the request works, returns with status 401 and the matcher fails. With more than one thread the test throws `ActionDispatch::IllegalStateError: header already sent` error. Logging `current_user` returns `nil`

Comment: The blog post was written for testing models/service objects. I am not sure if controllers tests are thread-safe in Rails. If there are many requests which request/response do you expect to be testing? It might be easier for you to test this logic if you extract non-http related concerns to a service and test that without doing HTTP requests.

Comment: @RobertPankowecki Moving the logic to a service object and rewriting the test for it fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know but it sounds like dispatch might not be threadsafe, what version of Rails are you using? Also all gems used in that code path would need to be threadsafe to get deterministic tests.

Comment: @Kris I'm using Rails 5.1.4 with ruby 2.4.2

Comment: Apparently this can be caused by older version Devise. But you found a work around anyway :)